# Tuneables/Configurable for a module

Tags: python, python-module

I am writing a module in python which has many functions to be used in a variety of situations, resulting in changing default values over time.  (Currently this is a .py file I am importing)  Many of the functions have the same hard-coded defaults.  I would like to make these defaults configureable, ideally through some functionality that can be accessed via a jupyter notebook that has already imported the module or at the very least that can be set at the time of import or via a config file.

I know how to do this using other languages but have been struggling to do the same in python.  I do not want defaults to be hardcoded.  I know that some of the difficulty with this is that the module is only imported once, meaning variables inside the module are no longer accessable after the import is complete.  If there is a way of looking at this more pythonically, I would accept an answer that explains why my desired solution is non-pythonic and what a good alternative would be.

For example here is what the functions would look like:

```
function1(arg1 = default_param1):
    return arg1
function2(arg1 = default_param1, arg2 = default_param3):
    other cool stuff
```

Here is what I would like to be able to do something similar to this:

```
import foo_module.py as foo
foo.function1()
foo.default_param1 = new_value
foo.function1()

==> arg1
==> new_value
```

Of course, with this setup you can always change the value input every time you call the function, but this is less than ideal.

In this case how would I change default_param1 accross the entire module via the code that is importing the module?

---

Edit: to clarify, this module would not be accessed via the command line.  A primary use case is to import it into a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Have you looked at environment variables?

Comment: You could also have a function like `my_module.set_default(key,value)` which updates the default values stored in a global `dict`.

Comment: re environment variables: - this program / module wouldn't be invoked via the command line.  Would env variables fit a use case if the module is imported into code running in jupyter notebook for instance?

Comment: @DanielWalker would this global dict be mutable after import?

Comment: It would, yeah.  Are you trying to set the defaults at the moment when you call `import` and have them be immutable after that?

Comment: @DanielWalker setting the defaults at the moment when you call import would be fine - mutability after that is not required, although I am curious about solutions that would solve either problem (immutability after import or mutability after import)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use environment variables such that, upon being imported, your module reads these variables and adjusts the defaults accordingly.

You could set the environment variables ahead of time using `os.environ`.  So,

```
import os

os.environ['BLAH'] = '5'
import my_module
```

Inside my_module.py, you'd have something like

```
import os

try:
    BLAH_DEFAULT = int(os.environ['BLAH'])
except:
    BLAH_DEFAULT = 3
```

If you'd rather not fiddle with environment variables and you're okay with the defaults being mutable after importation, my_module.py could store the defaults in a global `dict`.  E.g.

```
defaults = {
    'BLAH': 3,
    'FOO': 'bar',
    'BAZ': True
}
```

Your user could update that dictionary manually (`my_module.defaults['BAZ']=False`) or, if that bothers you, you could hide the mechanics in a function:

```
def update_default(key,value):
    if key not in defaults:
        raise ValueError('{} is not a valid default parameter.'.format(key))

    defaults[key]=value
```

You could spiff up that function by doing type/range checks on the passed value.

However, keep in mind that, unlike in languages like C++ and Java, nothing in Python is truly hidden.  A user would be able to directly reference `my_module.defaults` thus bypassing your function.

Comment: Thank you much for this - this should work for my needs.  If you also have a solution that would allow the param to be mutable after import please add it as well, I'd be very curious how to do that as well and/or example of your globdict idea.  Thanks again for such a quick response!

Comment: You're the best - thank you for the edit =D  This fully clarifies the points I wasn't understanding

Comment: My pleasure!  Happy coding!